# How do I properly call DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE inside a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I apologize for this relatively simple question but I am new to Oracle and DBMS Workspace Manager. I have a stored procedure that checks the current workspace and if it differs from the workspace being passed in it will execute the DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE. All the examples show using EXEC while calling DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE but when I have the following syntax inside TOAD it says its invalid, if I take the EXEC off no errors shown.

Which is correct?

```
 //Toad Does not like this synatx
 IF UPPER(l_current_workspace) != UPPER(i_workspace) THEN
        EXEC DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE (i_workspace); 
    END IF;
```

OR

```
//TOAD is fine with this
IF UPPER(l_current_workspace) != UPPER(i_workspace) THEN
        DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE (i_workspace); 
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the examples are in a form something like EXEC DBMS_WM.GOTOWORKSPACE (<>);`and not between a conditional`IF...END IF;`

`EXEC` is not a `PLSQL` reserved word.  It is a macro/shortcut in the client rather than the database server, that expands to wrap the statement it precedes into a `BEGIN ... END;` block.

It is used very widely on the command-line (SQLPlus and SQLcl) and editors like Toad and SQLDeveloper et al. often support it, but it is supported as a monolithic command only (EXEC as a prelude to the block) rather than inside of the block (Nested `EXEC` is not supported, nor is an `EXEC` inside  of another `BEGIN...END`; block).

Since it isn't a reserved word, expanding it when it is in another block is a problem. Parsing it becomes ambiguous -- one could define one's own function called `EXEC` and it would be perfectly valid to run in a `PLSQL` block.  The editor would then need to make an uncertain call about what to do when it encountered the word.  The below example would break if EXEC were expanded instead of being recognized as a procedure in the `PLSQL` block:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXEC(PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Param is:[%s]',PARAM_1));
  END EXEC;
/

BEGIN
  EXEC('VOLTRON');
END;
/
```

So the second example is correct (presuming it is housed in another `BEGIN...END;` block), and is universally compatible since it doesn't need to be intercepted and modified client-side.